# Continuity of a function different of zero

Tags: limits, continuity

The function $f$ is defined as:$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin x,& x \leq c \\ ax+b,&x>c\end{cases}$$
The value $a$ as $f$ will be continuous in $c \neq 0 $ is?

So, i got a test which said that the value is $a = \frac{\sin c - b}{c}$ but i'm not convinced of it.
I think that, for $c \neq 0 $, any value of $a$ can be correct, once $\sin x$ and $ax+b$ are continuous anyway.

And, in the case of $c = 0 $ that $$\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to c^+}f(x) = f(c)$$ which in case of the problem,is correct to $\sin x=ax+b$ so $a = \frac{\sin x-b}{x}$ with $x=c\neq 0$.
Can someone tell me if i'm wrong? And why can't $a\in\Bbb R$ be an answer?

Comment: If you replace $x=c$ in your formula for $a$ you get the exact same thing as them, not sure what your argument is.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are not correctly understanding what a function being continuous means. Of course, $sin(x)$ and $ax+b$ are individually continuous, but the function $f$ defined here is piecewise.

Now, to ensure continuity, the functional value of $f$ at $c$ must be equal to both the right and the left side limits of $f$ at the junction which is $x=c$.

Here, $$\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x) = sin(c)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x) = ac+b$$ which should now be equal to $f(c)$ which is $sin(c)$. Solving this, gives us $a = \frac{sin(c) - b}{c}$.